# restructure data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to restructure some data I have.  I currently have a data frame that looks like this...

```
Year    Cat   Number
2001    A     15
2001    B     2
2002    A     4
2002    B     12
```

But what I ultimately want is to have it in this shape...

```
Year    Cat    Number    Cat    Number
2001    A      15        B      2
2002    A      4         B      12
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance

:)

Comment: Different format, but how about `reshape(df, idvar = "Year", timevar = "Cat", direction = "wide")`

Comment: Not sure there is any point in having a column that is all "A" and another column that is all "B".  How about instead: `xtabs(Number ~., DF)`

Comment: Well, "anything is possible" :-), but just out of pure curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want a column of only A and a column of only B because I then want to add other columns of A% and B%.  So there only are two categories, A and B.  I'm a complete newbie at R so really just trying to solve the problem with the limited knowledge I have.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to  use `dcast/melt` from `reshape2`.  In the below code, first I created a sequence of numbers (`indx` column) for each `Year` by using `transform` and `ave`.  Then, `melt` the transformed dataset keeping `id.var` as `Year`, and `indx`.  The `long` format dataset is then reshaped to `wide` format using `dcast`.  If you don't need the suffix `_number`, you can use `gsub` to remove that part.

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(melt(transform(df, indx=ave(seq_along(Year), Year, FUN=seq_along)),
        id.var=c("Year", "indx")), Year~variable+indx, value.var="value")
colnames(res) <- gsub("\\_.*", "", colnames(res))
res
#   Year Cat Cat Number Number
#1 2001  A     B   15      2
#2 2002  A     B   4      12
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`.  Here, the idea is similar as above.  After grouping by `Year` column, generate a `indx` column using `mutate`, then reshape to long format with `gather`, `unite` two columns to a single column `VarIndx` and then reshape back to wide format with `spread`.  In the last step `mutate_each`, columns with names that start with `Number` are converted to `numeric` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res1 <-  df %>% 
             group_by(Year) %>%
             mutate(indx=row_number()) %>% 
             gather("Var", "Val", Cat:Number) %>%
             unite(VarIndx, Var, indx) %>%
             spread(VarIndx, Val) %>%
             mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), starts_with("Number")) 
 
 res1
 #  Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

  #  Year Cat_1 Cat_2 Number_1 Number_2
  #1 2001     A     B       15        2
  #2 2002     A     B        4       12
```

Or you can create an `indx` variable `.id` using `getanID` from `splitstackshape` (from comments made by @Ananda Mahto (author of splitstackshape) and use `reshape` from `base R`

```
  library(splitstackshape)
  reshape(getanID(df, "Year"), direction="wide", idvar="Year", timevar=".id")
  #   Year Cat.1 Number.1 Cat.2 Number.2
  #1: 2001     A       15     B        2
  #2: 2002     A        4     B       12
```

#### data

```
df <-   structure(list(Year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L), Cat = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B"), Number = c(15L, 2L, 4L, 12L)), .Names = c("Year", 
 "Cat", "Number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
 ))
```

Comment: `reshape(getanID(df, "Year"), direction = "wide", idvar = "Year", timevar = ".id")` (where `getanID` is from "splitstackshape") :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks for the comment.  It looks more compact now.

Comment: @akrun I have been going through the CRAN manual of splitstackshape. When I ran the sample code in the manual, I did not see an output. The code was running without errors. The same happen with this answer. I mean, if I just run `getanID(df, "Year")`, there is no output. So I guess I need to use getanID in another function. Is that right? I have a similar issue with `listCol_l` and `cSplit_f`. Codes are running, but no output. Please let me know if you have any insight.

Comment: @jazzurro I guess the version matters.  Yesterday, I had the same aha moment when I tried to replicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637864/splitting-a-column-delimiter-r/26638028#26638028 Later I found that it was only available in the new version.  So, please check if you have the latest version.  I installed the github version today and it runs on both the cases fine.

Comment: @akrun I have splitstackshape_1.4.2 which I got from CRAN. I will go to github and get that version now. Hmm no luck. I still see the same behaviour. When `getanID` is wrapped in another function like this example, I have no problem.